# Send mail via mailgun with attachment in delphi

Tags: http, delphi, email-attachments, mailgun

I try to send mail with added attachment. Mail arrives to the addresse withouth an attachment. I use api access in delphi (indy). Can anyone help me ? My code:

```
   try
      IdHTTP1.Request.CharSet       := 'utf-8';
      IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType   := 'multipart/form-data';
      IdHTTP1.Request.BasicAuthentication := True;
      IdHTTP1.Request.Username      := 'api';
      IdHTTP1.Request.Password      := 'my pass';

      Parametri := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;
      Parametri.AddFormField('from', UTF8Encode('Excited user<excited@sandbox.mailgun.org>'), 'utf-8').ContentTransfer := '8bit';
      Parametri.AddFormField('to','to@mail.com');
      Parametri.AddFormField('subject', UTF8Encode('xy: sub...'), 'utf-8').ContentTransfer := '8bit';
      Parametri.AddFormField('text', UTF8Encode('Here is my text...'), 'utf-8').ContentTransfer := '8bit';

      Parametri.AddFile('ABC.pdf', 'c:\ABC.pdf', '');
      Memo1.Text := IdHTTP1.Post( 'https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox.mailgun.org/messages', Parametri);
   finally  
      Parametri.Free;
   end;
```

Thank you,

b.

Comment: From the docs it looks like you need a form field for the attachment, `AddFormField('attachment' ...`

Answer (score 0):

Per the [MailGun API documentation](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-sending.html), each email attachment needs to be sent in a MIME field named `'attachment'`.  But when calling `AddFile()`, you are not naming the field `'attachment'`, you are naming it `'ABC.pdf'` instead.

Change this line:

```pascal
Parametri.AddFile('ABC.pdf', 'c:\ABC.pdf', '');
```

To this instead:

```pascal
Parametri.AddFile('attachment', 'c:\ABC.pdf');
```

Alternatively, the documentation also states that MailGun supports SMTP, so you could use `TIdSMTP` and `TIdMessage` instead of using `TIdHTTP` and `TIdMultipartFormDataStream`, and let `TIdMessage` handle the MIME formatting for you, eg:

```pascal
IdSMTP1.Host := 'smtp.mailgun.org';
IdSMTP.Username := 'api';
IdSMTP.Password := 'my pass';

IdMessage1.Clear;

IdMessage1.From.Name := 'Excited user';
IdMessage1.From.Address := 'excited@sandbox.mailgun.org';
IdMessage1.Recipients.EmailAddresses := 'to@mail.com';
IdMessage1.Subject := 'xy: sub...';

IdMessage1.ContentType := 'multipart/mixed';

with TIdText.Create(IdMessage1.MessageParts, nil) do
begin
  Body.Text := 'Here is my text...';
  ContentType := 'text/plain';
  CharSet := 'utf-8';
  ContentTransfer := '8-bit';
end;

TIdAttachmentFile.Create(IdMessage1.MessageParts, 'c:\ABC.pdf');

IdSMTP1.Connect;
try
  IdSMTP1.Send(IdMessage1);
finally
  IdSMTP1.Disconnect;
end;
```

Or:

```pascal
IdSMTP1.Host := 'smtp.mailgun.org';
IdSMTP.Username := 'api';
IdSMTP.Password := 'my pass';

IdMessage1.Clear;

IdMessage1.From.Name := 'Excited user';
IdMessage1.From.Address := 'excited@sandbox.mailgun.org';
IdMessage1.Recipients.EmailAddresses := 'to@mail.com';
IdMessage1.Subject := 'xy: sub...';

with TIdMessageBuilderPlain.Create do
try
  PlainText := 'Here is my text...';
  PlainTextCharSet := 'utf-8';
  PlainTextContentTransfer := '8-bit';

  Attachments.Add('c:\ABC.pdf');

  FillMessage(IdMessage1);
finally
  Free;
end;

IdSMTP1.Connect;
try
  IdSMTP1.Send(IdMessage1);
finally
  IdSMTP1.Disconnect;
end;
```